"Open.exe" from unidentified developer exists as a executable in my login items?
I cannot find anything on this binary - It does seems to function as stated when I use the command to open files, but I never installed it nor do I see it as a default executable in the bin folder of other Macs.
Not sure why it exists as a log in item:

Any ideas? Perhaps part of a .pkg that came with something else?

What is the exact path (as seen in a terminal)? Is it /bin/open? Can you [edit] your question and add what the output of ls -l <path to "open">, so that we can see the size, etc.. Which version of macOS?

macOS binaries are not .exe, applications are .app and referred to as app bundles. However, command line utilities generally have no extension, they are colloquially referred to as "binaries", though macOS tools such as the output from file lists them as an executable which is also correct, .exe is a Windows construct. open is an executable or a binary, but it is not a .exe, nor is its name open.exe

It seems as if there are a couple of possibilities for the source of /usr/bin/open:

If you are using Ventura, then it could have been installed as part of the OS (maybe 13.2.1, although there are conflicting reports)

It is part of LogMeIn - part of Citrix Online, if you installed that. Citrix are a legit company, but they do tend to fill your hard disk with cr*p
[Loaded] com.adobe.ccxprocess.plist (Adobe Inc. - installed 2023-02-14)

  Command: /usr/bin/open -a '/Applications/Utilities/Adobe Creative Cloud Experience/CCXProcess/CCXProcess.app'


It is part of Adobe Creative Cloud Experience, if you installed that
  [Loaded] com.adobe.ccxprocess.plist (Adobe Inc. - installed 2023-02-14)

  Command: /usr/bin/open -a '/Applications/Utilities/Adobe Creative Cloud Experience/CCXProcess/CCXProcess.app'

The relation to Adobe Creative Cloud Experience (via com.adobe.ccxprocess.plist) is also reiterated in the "best answer" in this link, I found an app called "Open" in the list of login items - can anyone identify what it is?


Source: usr/bin/open what is it? is it safe?
Note that the command line outputs were (apparently) created using a (seemingly useful) diagnostic tool called Etrecheck - I quoted the outputs from the link above - see Using EtreCheck for more information. I have never used this software though, so I can't (personally) vouch for its reliability/authenticity, although it seems legit.

You can find out more about open from the man page, by typing man open. As Marc Wilson has kindly pointed out, open has been around since the dawn of OS X, and prior.
Indeed, the bottom of the man page states the following:
HISTORY
     First appeared in NextStep.

So, in short, it is nothing to worry about.

FWIW, This question has also been asked over on SuperUser, Suspicious script meddling with /usr/bin/open.

How did you create the list/Terminal output? There might be other commands with login items, would be good if users could create that list themselves.

I quoted those outputs from the link. I believe that they were created using a diagnostic tool called "Etrecheck" (that I'd never heard of until today). However, I didn't want to mention that nor add a link to it, as it might be considered promotion and/or spam. However, in retrospect, maybe I should mention that in the answer, to avoid any confusion? I agree, it does seem rather useful indeed.

The Etrecheck diagnostic tool has been around for a while; the author is an active member of the Apple Discussions community.

I do run Citrix for accessing QB. And, sadly, creative cloud. Thanks for the responses. Worthy of note though, is since updating to Sonoma it is still there and Citrix functions just fine without it.

@user876 - Thanks for the update and info. However, the last line seems a bit contradictory. You say in Sonoma it is still there, so when you say that Citrix functions without it, does that mean that you removed or renamed it?

"Conflicting reports?"  The open command has been part of macOS for years.  Many years.

@MarcWilson - That may well be. However, I was referring to the conflicting reports in the linked thread. Kindly compare this post and this post with this post. The first two say that 13.2.1 resolved the issue, whereas the third says that it introduced the issue - if it is indeed an issue, at all.

@Greenonline The three posts you link make it plain that posters think open is a binary added by the various applications they talk about.  I cut to the chase and pointed out it was part of the OS.  Login items are using it to launch GUI apps, as you also point out in your answer by reading the actual plist files.  I’m not sure what Apple thought they were accomplishing by exposing LaunchAgents/Daemons that way... there's no issue (other than perhaps too many background apps running).
